# Rails: has_many through not returning results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

We recently upgraded rails to 5.1 following steps in the Rails guide, but see that the following is not working. I have the following model definitions

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_accounts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_accounts, :through => :user
end

class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try to execute, for example

```
user = User.find 109
member = user.members[0]
member.user_accounts

this generates the following query
```

```
SELECT `user_accounts`.* FROM `user_accounts` INNER JOIN `users` ON `user_accounts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `user_accounts`.`users` = NULL
```

users is getting checked with `NULL`

it should be users.id which is 109.

One important thing to mention is that the same `Member` model has other relationship using `through` with other models which work. for example

```
member.stores
member.credit_cards
```

but `member.user_accounts` does not work.

Any help on how to address this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: You can't `has_many` through a `belongs_to` ... You'll just need to `member.user.user_accounts`

Comment: sorry I don't understand? do you suggest Rails 5 does not support it as this was working in an earlier version of rails

Comment: The user accounts don't belong to member, they belong to user, and there are many members belonging to user ... You'd be better off creating: `def user_accounts ; user.user_accounts ; end` rather than a `belongs_to` if you don't want to call it directly

Comment: Why don't you add a simple `delegate :user_accounts, to: :user` to our `Member` class?

Comment: @mechnicov, that did not work

Comment: @spickermann, that works, but I want to know why not a simple `through` is working? also for the same model, there are other relationships via `through` which work

Comment: seems to work fine, even if a bit backwards. `user_accounts.users = NULL` is that a `users` column in `user_accounts`? you must have something else messing with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like I have to put this here:

> *`:through` Specifies an association through which to perform the query. This can be **any other type of association**...
>
> https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many.*

---

I've set up models, just like you show, working fine:

```rb
>> Member.first.user.user_accounts
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UserAccount id: 1, user_id: 1>]>

# through: user
>> Member.first.user_accounts
Member Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` ORDER BY `members`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
UserAccount Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `user_accounts`.* FROM `user_accounts` INNER JOIN `users` ON `user_accounts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UserAccount id: 1, user_id: 1>]>
```

Here's how I broke it:

```rb
class AddUsersToUserAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :user_accounts, :users, :integer
  end
end
```

```
>> Member.first.user_accounts
Member Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` ORDER BY `members`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
UserAccount Load (0.7ms)  
  SELECT  `user_accounts`.* FROM `user_accounts` 
  INNER JOIN `users` ON `user_accounts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
  WHERE `user_accounts`.`users` = NULL LIMIT 11
#                        ^
# using `users` column instead
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

```rb
>> UserAccount.column_names
=> ["id", "user_id", "users"]
>> Member.first.user_accounts.arel.ast.cores[0].wheres[0].children[0].to_sql
=> "`user_accounts`.`users` = ?"
```

When `users.id = 1` *where* clause is being built, arel takes a hash `{"users"=>{"id"=>1}}` and spits out some sql. If there is a `users` column present, it stumbles on this part and treats `"users"` key as a column instead of a table:

```rb
when value.is_a?(Hash) && !table.has_column?(column_name)
#                         ^^^^^^^^^ this one ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.7/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L91*

When I rollback and remove `users` column, it goes into the correct branch and builds a working sql:

```rb
>> UserAccount.column_names
=> ["id", "user_id"]
>> Member.first.user_accounts.arel.ast.cores[0].wheres[0].children[0].to_sql
=> "`users`.`id` = ?"
```

Comment: you are the best, that was the reason, the table has a `users` column

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :through` association works on **many-to-many** relationships. `belongs_to :user` definition in your Member model returns a single object, but `has_many :through` association expects collection of objects in the `through` definition. So, this association will not work.

To access all user accounts for a member, you need to first remove this association from **Member** model `has_many :user_accounts, :through => :user` and follow one of the below approaches:

1. use `member.user.user_accounts`
2. Specify `delegate` directive on the **Member** model like this `delegate :user_acconts, to: :user` and use `member.user_accounts`

See the documentation of `has_many :through` association [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: *has_many :through association works on many-to-many relationships. belongs_to :user definition in your Member model returns a single object, but has_many :through association expects collection of objects in the through definition. So, this association will not work* — are you sure? Can you add reference to rails source?